# Empty string (char *) received from codecvt

Tags: c++11, string-conversion

ALL,

I have a following code:

In the header

```
class MySQLDatabase
{
protected:
    struct MySQLImpl;
    MySQLImpl *m_pimpl;
};

struct MySQLDatabase::MySQLImpl
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > m_myconv;
    std::wstring m_host, m_user, m_password, m_dbName, m_socket, m_catalog;
};
```

In the cpp

```
int MySQLDatabase::Connect()
{
            std::wstring tname;
// some code here
            const char *temp1 = m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( tname.c_str() ).c_str();
            const char *temp2 = m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( ownerName.c_str() ).c_str();
            const char *temp3 = m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( fieldName.c_str() ).c_str();
            unsigned long str_length1 = strlen( temp1 ), str_length2 = strlen( temp2 ), str_length3 = strlen( temp3 );
            str_data1 = new char[str_length1 + 1], str_data2 = new char[str_length2 + 1], str_data3 = new char[str_length3 + 1];
            memset( str_data1, '\0', str_length1 + 1 );
            memset( str_data2, '\0', str_length2 + 1 );
            memset( str_data3, '\0', str_length3 + 1 );
// some more code here
}
```

I am trying to compile and run this code on Linux with gcc 5.4 in c++11 mode.
The tname variable contains L"draft.abc\303\237".

The problem is that the temp1 is "" (empty string). And so is temp2 and temp3 (ownerName is L"" and fieldName is L"name").

Am I doing something wrong with the conversion?

Comment: `m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes(...)` returns a temporary string. Then you save a pointer to the data managed by that temporary. Then the temporary is destroyed, taking the data with it and leaving the pointer dangling. Then you use that pointer, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, do you have a pointer to documentation where it says it returns a temporary string? Also in order to fix it I should use strcpy(), right?

Comment: It returns an instance of `std::string` by value. This return value is, by definition, a temporary object. You should store it in a variable of type `std::string` - I'm not sure why you insist on using C-style strings.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, because mySQL interface I'm using needs `char *`. So I should write: `std::string temp = m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes( tname.c_str() ).c_str();` and then pass `temp.c_str()` to mysql? Will that work?

Comment: `std::string temp = m_pimpl->m_myconv.to_bytes(tname);` should do it.